# Sentence true in A=(N, <) but false in B=(N, >)

Tags: logic

Let $A=(N,<)$ and $B=(N, >)$ where $N$ denotes the set of natural number and $<,>$ the usual binary relation.

I am asked to find a sentence true in one but false in the other.

I understand how to proceed when the difference between the two structures deal with the nature of the set or binary operations such as multiplication vs addition but I am having a hard with this one.

Both these structures seem to share every properties (transitivity...).

A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $(\forall x) ((1 R x) \lor (1 = x))$.

Comment: $\forall x\,\exists y\,(x<y)$

Comment: What is the context for this question? "<" and ">" are different symbols so $(N, <)$ and $(N, >)$ are structures for two different signatures. The only sentences that have truth values in both structures are those that don't use either "<" or ">".

Comment: @Rob Arthan: It's clear that both structures are being taken as $L$-structures for $L$ the language with a single binary relation symbol.

Comment: @Reese: that is not at all clear and it comprises a gross abuse of standard model theory terminology. That's why I raised the comment (because I suspect the OP is being set questions by someone who is abusing the standard terminology).

Comment: @Rob Arthan: I don't know about you, but I often see this sort of notation used rather than the technically-correct but absurdly unwieldy "Let $A$ be the structure with signature $(M,R)$ in which $M$ is interpreted as $\mathbb{N}$ and $R$ is interpreted as $<$..." For example, we say $(M,R) \models ZFC$ if it models $ZFC$ with $R$ interpreted as $\in$. Also, given that (as you pointed out) the question is nonsensical without this interpretation, it seems bizarre to interpret it otherwise, which is exactly what I mean by "clear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $N$ were "symmetrical" with respect to $<$ (for example, if we were talking about $Z$ instead), then it wouldn't be possible - so the key must be asymmetry. What's the most striking way that $N$ is asymmetrical? To me, the most glaring asymmetry is $0$ (or $1$, if your natural numbers start at $1$). See if you can come up with a sentence about that starting number.

Comment: I confused N and Z. Obvious now with the "boundness" of N. In the same fashion, one could not come up with such an expression between (Q, <) and (R, <) since they share their symmetry.

Comment: The question and the above answer make no sense at all with the usual definition of the semantics of first order logic. See my comment on the question.